# Make histogram from CSV file with python

Tags: python, histogram

I have written this code to perform a histogram from a `.csv` file however I do not get the histogram but as you see in the image

[image]

how can I fix it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

plt.hist(data)

plt.show()
```

The head lines in the `.csv` file are:

```
-95.725
-78.477
-77.976
-77.01
-73.161
-72.505
-71.794
-71.036
-70.653
-70.476
-69.32
-68.787
-68.234
-67.968
-67.742
-67.611
-67.577
-66.69
-66.381
-66.172
-66.072
-65.773
-64.969
-64.897
-64.603
```

Comment: What is the type and shape of `data` after `read_csv`? You get many histograms with 1 entry each, so you probably need to reshape `data` into a pandas.Series or a 1D numpy array.

Comment: first check `data.head()` to see what you have.

Comment: as for me it can be correct histogram for your data. What did you expect ?

Comment: I was expecting a histogram with bars, how can I process my data for this?, for instance: [http://danielhnyk.cz/fitting-distribution-histogram-using-python/?fbclid=IwAR2Eg104vU-fgXPEof-ROeFEEI2e0oOTLayS2uVKUT6wQ3drKCSjbIgTeaU]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try adding the keyword parameters `bins='auto'`, `density=True` and `histtype='step'` to the `plt.hist` function.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

plt.hist(data, bins='auto', density=True, histtype='step')

plt.show()
```

What they each do is:

- `bins='auto'`: Lets numpy automatically decide on the best bin edges;
- `density=True`: Sets the area within the histogram to equal 1.0;
- `histtype='bar'`: Gives the bar style look for the histogram.

This and more can all be found in the [matplotlib API](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Comment: Hhmm, could you display your pandas DataFrame object? To see what the headers appear like?

Comment: You may need to specify a number for `bins`, since your widths are very small.

Comment: Just saw that you do actually want it to appear like a bar plot, you should try changing `histtype` to `histtype='bar'`. If we can get the overall shape working, then we can change the face- and edge-colors easily. I'm saying this since the problem appears to the distribution of your data.

Comment: DataFrame is: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. How to process my data ? histtype doesn't work for me.

Comment: Okay, so the data frame is not the problem. If `histtype` is not working you should just be able to remove it as an argument since it defaults to `'bar'` anyway. Try setting `bins=10` to see if that gives something similar to what you had in mind.

Comment: with the function sns.distplot I achieve something similar to what I want but not with plt.hist, I do not understand why?